# Display several confidence intervals in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with rows corresponding the the upper and lower limits of confidence intervals for a parameter. If there are n rows, there are n variables. There are two columns, one with the lower confidence interval limit "lower" and one for the "upper" limit. The row names correspond to the variable names. Something like this

```
      lower  upper  
y1      7.923  9.22
y2      7.105  8.74 
y3      8.185  9.54 
y4      8.157  9.51
```

I would like to create a plot to display these confidence intervals as bars, preferably with flanges at each end.

If someone could tell me a good way to do this I would be grateful !

Thanks
PS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bwplot` in `lattice` makes box-and-whisker plots:

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(lower+upper~var, data=dat)
```

See `?bwplot` and `?lattice` for more detail.

[image]

---

In general, you can use the full power of R by letting the plot function summarise the dat for you.  For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  var <- sample(paste("y", 1:4, sep=""), 100, replace=TRUE),
  val <- rnorm(100)
  )

plot(val~factor(var), data=dat, col="cyan")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! The first plot above looks like what I would like, but I was unable to make it work. What is "var" in your example code: bwplot(lower+upper~var, data=dat)
?

Comment: @P Sellaz `var` is a factor constructed to denote where the data comes from (from y1, y2, y3, y4). In your case, this would be row names.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still having trouble with that.
bwplot(lower+upper~y1, data=cidf)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y1' not found

Comment: Is `y1` the name of a column in your data.frame?

Comment: Thanks. No, the column names are "lower" and "upper". The y1,y2,y3,y4 etc are row names corresponding to the names of parameters. The values of the two columns are the upper and lower limts of confidence intervals for the parameters, that I wish to plot. I was able to make it work using boxplot() after converting the df to a matrix, but I'd like to get it working with bwplot and/or ggplot if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the customary `ggplot2` solution. There are several other `geoms` available for this kind of a plot. For instance try replacing with `geom_crossbar`. For more details, visit [the ggplot2 webpage](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)

```
cidf = data.frame(
   var   = c('y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'),
   lower = c(7.923, 7.105, 8.185, 8.157),
   upper = c(9.22, 8.74, 9.54, 9.51)
)

require(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(cidf) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = var, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks. It sounds promising, but as per my comment to the other answer, I don't know what "var" represents in your example code. For instance I have a dataframe called cidf and it has columns "lower" and "upper" with each row being an interval that I want to display. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh, got it now. Thanks ! So I need to add another column to the dataframe - basically to convert the row names to factors, as per what Roman Luštrik said above. Sorry for being a bit slow !

Comment: I found that I can just use x=row.names(cidf) instead of making a new column.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find one way to do it with the inbuilt boxplot command. I had to change the data frame to a matrix though:

```
ci <- as.matrix(cidf)
boxplot(ci[1,],ci[2,],ci[3,],ci[4,])
```

I'd still be interested to know a nicer way to do it in `ggplot` or `bwplot`, or any other relevant advice.

PS

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have a nice solution with ggplot. Thanks to the responses above

```
p1 <- ggplot(cidf) +

geom_errorbar(aes(x = row.names(ciddf), ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2) +

xlab("Variables") +

coord_flip() + opts(title = "Confidence intervals for Variables")

p1
```